# Solve for $x$ and $y$ in integers.

Tags: diophantine-equations

> In the equation $x^3+y^3=(x+y)^2$, solve for $x$ and $y$ in integers.

So far, I factorized and cancelled out a copy of $(x+y)$ on both sides, leaving me with $x+y=x^2-xy+y^2$. Then, I added $xy+1$ on both sides, and got $(x+1)(y+1)=x^2+y^2+1$. I can't continue from this point.

Comment: When you cancelled $x+y$ from both sides, you lost all solutions of the form $y=-x$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805246/find-all-pairs-of-integers-x-y-such-that-x3y3-xy2?noredirect=1 may help.

Comment: @Tan: The accepted solution at your link is missing the solution $(x,y)=(2.2)$.

Comment: Maybe, starting from $x+y=x^2-xy+y^2$, you should add $3xy$ to both sides to conclude that $(x+y) + 3xy = (x+y)^2$. This way you know that $3xy$ is dividable by $x+y$. Since we can assume that $(x,y) = 1$ this would lead to $3|(x+y)$  leading to four options on $x+y$, that is $x+y = 1,-1,3,-3$

Comment: @TonyK It seems that they found it but forgot to write at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write everything on one side and factor (and not discard infinite families of solutions).
\begin{align*}
x^3 + y^3 - (x+y)^2 &= 0  \\
(x+y)(y^2 - xy + x^2 -y -x) &= 0
\end{align*}

A product is zero when any factor is zero, so, from $x+y = 0$, we find the infinite family of solutions
$$  y = -x  \text{.}  $$
Now we attack $y^2 - xy + x^2 -y -x = 0$.  Note that this is the equation of an ellipse with major axis parallel to the line $y = x$ and  centered at $(1,1)$.  If you sketch that ellipse, you will find that it is in the box $\left[\frac{1}{3}(3 - 2 \sqrt{3}),\frac{1}{3}(3 + 2 \sqrt{3})\right] \times{}$ $\left[\frac{1}{3}(3 - 2 \sqrt{3}),\frac{1}{3}(3 + 2 \sqrt{3})\right]$.  So we check the nine integer points in that box. (We could exclude $(1,1)$ since it is the center, but the automatic/unthinking way to proceed is to check every point in the box).
\begin{align*}
&x  &  &y  &  y^2 - xy + &x^2 -y -x  &  \\ \hline
&0  &  &0  &  0&  &\checkmark  \\
&0  &  &1  &  0&  &\checkmark  \\
&0  &  &2  &  2&  &  \\
&1  &  &0  &  0&  &\checkmark  \\
&1  &  &1  &  -1&  &  \\
&1  &  &2  &  0&  &\checkmark  \\
&2  &  &0  &  2&  &  \\
&2  &  &1  &  0&  &\checkmark  \\
&2  &  &2  &  0&  &\checkmark  \\
\end{align*}

So the full solution set is $\{(x,y) \mid y = -x\} \cup {}$ $\{(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$, $(2,2)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplified expression that you obtained defines an ellipse:

[image]

Additionally, the line $y=-x$ also satisfies the relation and so, apart from the solutions already found on the elipse ($(0,0), (1,0), (0,1),(2,1),(1,2)$ and $(2,2)$), you also get all points of the form $(n,-n), n \in \mathbb{Z}$.